# c# passing instance of different Windows.Forms types

Tags: c#

I have a function, which accepts a Parameter from type `System.Windows.Forms.Label`, so im able to pass a specific Label-Instance, so far so good.

But i want to keep this Parameter as flexible as possible. So for example, i want also to be able to pass a Textbox-Instance as Parameter to the function, or anything else, **which provides the `.Text` property and is `invokeable`**.

So I have this:

```
public void Test(Label targetLabel) { //stuff }
```

But i want something as flexible as possible, something like

```
public void Test(object target) { //stuff }
```

--> but then how do i convert `target` into the right Type which is

a) `Invokeable`

b) has the property `.Text`

- otherwise throw exception or something?

Comment: check up about interfaces

Comment: How about `Control`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accept anything of Type `System.Windows.Forms.Control`.

[Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx) is the Class that first declares the .Text property and also implements the [`ISynchronizeInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) interface (which brings the `*Invoke` methods into play).